# DataTables jQuery Multiples Tables Query

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have jQuery DataTables and would like to use multiple tables in Querying the MySQL Database.

Table Viewers

```
ID | USER | CREATED | ACTIVE | PACKET
-------------------------------------
1   user01  22/12/13 01/01/13    6
2   user02  19/12/13 01/01/13    23
```

Table Packets

```
 ID | PACKET
-------------------------------------
 6    FULL
 23   LIMITED
```

I would like to get from Table Viewers Packet number and then INNER JOIN it with Table Packets ID to get packet name for that Packet(for example: packet 6 - FULL, packet 23 - LIMITED)

in server side processing i im traying to define two tables but it give me error.

here is for one table, how to add multiple tables so that i can use INNER JOIN FROM $table WHERE viewers.packet = packets.packet

```
  $aColumns = array( 'id', 'user', 'created', 'active', 'packet', 'dealer', 'dealer', 'id', 'id');

  $sTable = 'viewers';

  $sJoin = 'INNER JOIN packets ON viewers.packet = packets.packet ';


  $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sJoin
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
";
```

I have trying with:

```
  $aColumns = array( 'v.id', 'v.user', 'v.created', 'v.active', 'v.packet', 'v.dealer', 'v.dealer', 'v.id', 'p.packets');

  $sTable = "'viewers v', 'packets p'";
```

But in json encode is see that i have correct number of rows but aadata is null for all objects read from database. Any help? I have trying 3days and no go.

Comment: first thing I noticed in your join string is that you made `viewers.packet = packets.packet` instead of `viewers.packet = packets.id` retry fixing that and reply back

Comment: i fixed it...it must be added my own queryin server-processing.php and then retrieved via json to client side to be shown by datatables.